# NetSuite Webservice Client generation

Tags: web-services, netsuite

I am trying to setup the NS webservice from eclipse or stand alone command line. As per the instruction given by them i downloaded axis. Added the patch for the axis and also did setup that is required to do. Initially I was getting a time out issue. But later I found a way to fix this. But the problem occurs that it does not create all the class. I found that the ApplicaionInfo class in platform package is missing. and also this gives 255 parameter limitation issue. Is any one has experience doing the same or setting up.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

the constructors with > 255 params are never used by generated code so you can safely delete them from the generated source.

Once you've done that I believe everything will compile to .class files.

Comment: Great ! thats what I tried to comment those class. 
Mean while I found that ApplicationInfo class is also not getting generated. This class is needed to pass the login parameter. Any thought ?

Comment: What version of SuiteTalk are you using?

Comment: I am using 2017_1 and 2017_2 . Both tries.

Comment: I'm using 2015.2 I don't see any issues with ApplicationInfo. java in terms of constructor parameter counts or anything. What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Ok. I did use of this.
https://github.com/Topher84/NetSuite-WS-2017.1-Java